# Cannot Enter Magento admin panel and credentials are not working

Tags: admin

http://lecoqcuisine.com/admin

This is website was created in magento  few years back and this magento version is also out-dated now.
i have a requirement to update few pages on website. But credentials i have is not working and forget password email id is also deactivated few years ago.

Please help how to get into admin panel , so i can change front end and fix website.
Thanks In Advance !

Comment: Are you asking the people here to hack a website? oO

Comment: Is the only way left ?

Comment: Do you have access to the hosting / server?

Comment: Hosting Server - Yes

Comment: https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_reset_admin_password_in_magento/

Answer (score 0):

Please create a new admin account by SSH terminal by this below command

**php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user=admin --admin-password=your-password --admin-email=hi@test.com --admin-firstname=firstname --admin-lastname=lastname**

Please put the varriable in above command as your specific like

1. --admin-user=admin
2. --admin-password=your-password
3. --admin-email=hi@test.com
4. --admin-firstname=firstname
5. --admin-lastname=lastname

after that you can login with the 'admin-username' and 'admin-password'.

Comment: OP is on Magento1...

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server, you can execute the following SQL command to set your admin password:

`` UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = md5('YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD'), is_active = 1 WHERE `username` = 'YOUR_ADMIN_USERNAME'; ``